# Where can I store my items?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I'm only starting *Divinity: Original Sin*. And I don't know yet if some items will be useful or not. So I'm currently keeping everything (mostly ingredients), but it takes place.

So where can I safely store my items? I read that I'll get a "living quarters" during the main quest, which is said to be a safe place. I'm not there yet, so is there any other place I can use meanwhile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be long before you:

> Discover your homestead, at which point you can send items there by right-clicking them.

Until then, between four characters you should have sufficient carrying capacity to just keep it all in your inventory. But if you don't, pick any spot you can easily get back to later (near a portal) and drop stuff on the ground or shove it in a chest. If you want, you can even pick up chests, barrels or crates (may require some Strength or Telekinesis) and put them where you want them.

> The forge behind the abandoned shop in Cyseal is a nice location for that.

Comment: So this means items stay in the place where I put them permanently? No NPC's will run with the goods and sell them? :)

Comment: Never had any vanish, although I only used it until discovering the ... other place.